# How to go back from new activity to main navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

First I create app of Navigation Drawer Activity and travel from fragment to new activity, Now I want to set Home Button on New activity which navigates to main activity of navigation drawer.
but when i run it from app it gives me this when Home button is click
[image: firts]

but i want to go direct on MainActivity
 Here 
[image]

NewActivity.java

```
package com.shubham.navi_demo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class NewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static Button Button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    onclickbutton();
}

public void onclickbutton(){
    Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
 }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.shubham.navi_demo.NewActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: which activity are you calling here?
` Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");`

Comment: you can do it in this way also:
Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

Comment: I want to call activity_main.xml from new activity

Comment: Thank you so much it works,

Comment: i love stackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to start `activity` with `Intent`. Just call `finish()` in `NewActivity`, it will show you the `Main Navigation drawer activity`.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
```

to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
```

or call finish(); to finish() current Activity

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that you can provide users to navigate back to home screen is explained here.
developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Add this line to your 'AndroidManifest' under relevant activity declaration.

> android:parentActivityName="com.example.your_main_activity"